# How pass selected index value to a change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a select menu that looks like this:

```
<select id ="cal-category-select">
    <option value="/event-sort/list/2009/9/sports/">Sports Events</option>
    <option value="/event-sort/list/2009/9/fine-arts/">Fine Arts Events</option>
    ...
</select>
```

When the user selects an option from the select, I need to pass the option value attribute to this function as event data, it's the second parameter:

```
$('#cal-category-select').bind('change.filter', need_value_attribute_here, update_cal);
```

The `update_cal` function referenced receives the data passed in from the second parameter and using to get some ajax content.

Any idea how I can do that? I haven't been able to get it to work.

I have tried this:

```
var category_url = $('#cal-category-select option:selected').attr('value');
$('#cal-category-select').unbind().bind('change.filter', category_url, update_cal);
```

but that only returns the first option value in the list.

Comment: Is `change.filter` your own defined custom event?

Comment: it's the change event with the filter namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just use:

```
$("#cal-category-select").val()
```

alternative longer syntax:

```
$('#cal-category-select option:selected').val()
```

Comment: .val() does get me the value correctly

but it still seems to return the value of the first option in the select (the one selected at the time of page load)

I am looking for the value of the one that gets selected

does that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#cal-category-select').bind('change.filter', function(){
  update_cal($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the selected `<option>` value, it should just be

```
$('#cal-category-select').val();
```